# Rails 3 gem: Simple Scraper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a good scraper gem for rails? I remember reading a blog post about one recently but can't find it atm.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/), also checkout 
[SelectorGadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/) - generates CSS selectors for you

Answer (score 1):

Lots exist. Try ScrAPI (see http://railscasts.com/episodes/173-screen-scraping-with-scrapi) or Nokogiri (see http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri).

Answer (score 1):

Tried both ScrAPI and Nokogiri for an application of mine.

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) is much more robust to different encodings (utf, windows-XXXX, etc). It just works.

With [ScrAPI](https://rubyforge.org/projects/scrapi/), I had to detect the encoding first as described [in this article](http://www.quarkruby.com/2009/9/22/rails-utf-8-and-html-screen-scraping). No worries with Nokogiri, as it handles the encoding gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize, Hpricot are also very useful. Refer to following links to know how to start with these tools -

http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/04/simple-ruby-screen-scraper-using.html (Simple Ruby Screen Scraper using Mechanize, Hpricot and XPath )

http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/04/simple-ruby-screen-scraper-in-just-5.html (Simple Ruby Screen Scraper in just 5 lines without using XPath )